# how to make guest user see build log in private project of gitlab 8.8

Tags: gitlab

I give a user guest role in my private project, want him to see my project build log.  but I find that him cannot see the build log.

here is my research

1. In [gitlab Permissions document](http://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/permissions.html#gitlab-ci) , I see the guest role has the right to see build log.
2. I find the sentence "If Allow guest to access builds is enabled in CI settings "  but I can not find the CI setting in the gitlab 8.8

Answer (score 0):

"[CI Quick Start](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/93106e150d4810459d0fc82b8c552309db4431fc/doc/ci/quick_start/README.md)" (and [user permissions](https://gitlab.com/help/user/permissions.md)) are not up-to-date.
As mentioned in "[Migrate GitLab CI to GitLab CE or EE](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/ef4fedc18f5e2475aa36cc4327a76a496567c6fc/doc/migrate_ci_to_ce/README.md)"

> CI settings are now in GitLab
>
> If you want to use custom CI settings (e.g. change where builds are stored), please update `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` (Omnibus) or `/home/git/gitlab/config/gitlab.yml` (Source).

[As of GitLab 8.3.0, the dedicated `CI settings` section was removed](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/commit/e80e3f5372d6bcad1fbe04a85b3086bb66794828), and those settings are integrated in the various other project settings (like the runners section)

This [GitLab CE issue search](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&issue_search=guest&label_name%5B%5D=CI) mentions access issues for guest like [issue 18448](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/18448):

> I think that 'Allow guest to access builds` works only for public projects

Nothing specific to the logs though.

Comment: The CI is actived in my gitlab ce 8.8 and I have use it to auto build, deploy my project.  I just can't  find the menu Settings > CI settings.  how can I active it.

Comment: @lan it is a menu associated to a GitLab project. Are you in a project page?

Comment: yes, I in my gitlab project, then enter in settings menu,  then  I just see these menu:  [Project Settings], [Groups], [Deploys Keys], [Webhooks], [Services], [Protected branch], [Runner], [Variables], [Triggers], [Badges]

Comment: @lan I see the documentation is not updated: those settings were removed in GitLab 8.3.0: https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/commit/e80e3f5372d6bcad1fbe04a85b3086bb66794828

Comment: @lan investigating https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/de204b9565cbe5f614ada9ea4f89c6b3495b7d0a/CHANGELOG#L742

Comment: I can access the url /ci/lint.  It just a a tool to check my .gitlab-ci.yml.